# Create Table with remote sorting, pagination, filtering

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am really new in react / redux.

I have read and studied all the documentation and examples, now I'm trying to create a table (not fixed-data-table), that the data collected from the server, allows me to perform paging, sorting and filtering content.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to proceed, and I can not find examples useful to understand how to do.

There is someone who could give me some examples in order to build these components and that they can communicate via redux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) is a great guide aimed at getting you comfortable with React state model. It explains how to build a table with filtering, but sorting can be implemented in a similar way. This example doesn’t use Redux, but a Redux implementation would be similar, with the exception that the state would be managed by reducers instead of the top-level component.

To make filtering and sorting efficient in Redux, it is usually combined with memoization. [Computing Derived Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) shows how you can use [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) to create composable data selectors that can filter and sort it.

As for pagination, the [`real-world` example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world) in Redux repo shows how to implement it. It requires a deeper understanding of topics such as state normalization so don’t jump into it too soon. But the basic idea is to store the rows separately from a list of their IDs, and use a data structure like `{ ids: array, isFetching: bool, nextPageUrl: string? }` to represent the pagination state.

Comment: Is there an example which shows paging/sorting with creating data as well? The real world example is cool but it only reads from an API. I find it gets really tricky when you e.g. want to create a record and need to now to which page the new record belongs to update the state accordingly. It gets even more complicated when you have paging combined with sorting.

Comment: @Gambo what did you end up doing for paging and sorting. I am similarly new to react/redux and having trouble finding a solution.

Comment: @CalebSandfort - I ended up overwriting my local state with the one I get from the server which is not perfect but I don't know a better solution. You could argue if I need state management at all if I am always taking the server state. I thought about adding a new layer which stores all data in IndexDB but I could not find any examples for this as well.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a package called [violet-paginator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/violet-paginator) to handle pagination, sorting, and filtering of any list. There are many ways to override the default assumptions made about communication with the server, so it should work for most cases. It exposes all the actions you'd need to create your own pagination components, as well as quite a few pre-made components including pagination controls, sort links, and data tables.